# calling list item where var = value

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

is there a way of calling a specific list of lists without having to check (or loop) them all?

it is easier to understand with an example....

lets say

```
callList(5).key = "1234"
callList(5).callOpened = "11/26/13"
```

now i want to do something like

```
 textbox_callOpened.text = callList(where key = "1234").callOpened
```

i also need to know what index that was at for there are many more items that i need to output too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [LINQ](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb763068.aspx). Add `Imports System.Linq` at top of the file and use `First` method with [lambda expression](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb531253.aspx) as a predicate to get what you need:

```
' that gives you item matching your predicate '
Dim item = callList.First(Function(x) x.Key = "1234")

' you can use it to set the property '
textbox_callOpened.text = item.callOpened
```

Comment: dont forget the null reference if not found

Comment: If element is not found it will not be `NullReferenceException`. It will be `InvalidOperationException`.

Comment: true, with "First" it wont return a null object if none are found. I forgot about that one.

Answer (score 0):

pseudo code, didn't test but should work

```
    dim something = callList.firstordefault(function(d) d.key = "1234")

    if something is not nothing then
         textbox_callOpened.text = something.callOpened 
    else
        'cant find an element with key 1234
    end if
```

Comment: can you please explain? i do not understand the 

   function(d) d.key

right now i am doing something like....

       Dim a As Integer
        For i = 0 To calllist.Count
            If calllist(i).key = "1234" Then
                a = i
            End If
        Next

Comment: @Ishey4, i wont try to explain how lambda work but i will give you this link that explain it; http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb531253.aspx

Comment: wow! i will have to go through that with a comb.. looks like a lot of info there... ty
i take it back.. not so much... it seems kinda like a mini function or sub plus